# Scan image like X- Ray in IOS

Tags: ios, image-processing, image-scanner

I took a picture from iPhone camera.Now I want to scan the image like X-Ray scanning. Let consider I took a picture of an arm and then by programming/Algorithm it will scan the photo and will display the bone inside the arm. Are there any image processing library which can do similar type of thing?
I have tried to get the upper thing by several things provided by apple using core image but did not get anything which I am looking for.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html

Does anybody have any solutions regarding this?

Thanks

Comment: You mean a real X-ray? That's not possible in the slightest. The camera doesn't record X-rays (nor any light anywhere close to that wavelength). Or do you mean using image analysis to recognize that something is a body part, then overlay an image of a bone over that body part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. What you are asking for is fundamentally impossible -- the iPhone camera cannot see through solid objects. (And I can't believe I just had to say that.)

Comment: I think so. But There are some apps in market they are telling that they are doing so.Please check below linkshttps://itunes.apple.com/in/app/x-ray-scanner.-x-ray-vision/id401807557?mt=8
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/x-ray-scan-get-2-apps-in-1/id452251485?mt=8

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/x-ray-scan-+-free/id466234654?mt=8

Comment: Those (at best) are simulations. They're doing a little bit of image analysis, doing a little bit of filtering, then slapping fake bones on top of the image. Or, at worst, just throwing totally fake, prerendered images up and acting like the camera is recording it. None of them are taking REAL X-rays (or anything close).

Comment: Ha fakkkkeeee... they are just simulations not REAL x rays

Comment: The reviews on those applications should be a clue -- much like "fingerprint scan", "phone tracker", and "lie detector" applications, they do not actually have X-ray functionality.